# How to generate the same cxx method mangled name with LLVM?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, name-mangling

I have an iOS project, and in my project I have a c++ method:

```
ClassA::getElements(vector<vector<int> >&ovElements) {
    // ...
}
```

I built my project by `xcodebuild` command, and from the `.o` file, I get to know its mangled name is `__ZN25ClassA18getElementsERNSt3__16vectorINS1_IiNS0_9allocatorIiEEEENS2_IS4_EEEE`. its demangled name should be `ClassA::getElements(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >&)`

I am trying to develop a clang tool to export all functions/methods boundaries along with their names from source files. I could make use of `MatchFinder` to find all `cxxMethod` and `function` and get their `FunctionDecl`, then I use the following method to get their mangled names:

```
std::string getMangledName(const FunctionDecl *FD, const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
    auto mangleContext = Result.Context->createMangleContext();

    if (!mangleContext->shouldMangleDeclName(FD)) {
      return FD->getNameInfo().getName().getAsString();
    }

    std::string mangledName;
    llvm::raw_string_ostream ostream(mangledName);

    mangleContext->mangleName(FD, ostream);

    ostream.flush();

    delete mangleContext;

    return mangledName;
  }
```

But for this `ClassA::getElements` method, I get `_ZN25ClassA18getElementsERii`, which is not I want. After demangling it, I find its name is `ClassA::getElements(int&)`.

BTW, the compilation database I used is generated by `xcpretty`,

```
xcodebuild ... | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database
```

My question is why I get `int&` rather than `std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >&`.
How can I get the same mangled name that the compiler generated?

---

I followed the comment from @user17732522 and set up a minimal project that only contains `Test.hpp`

```
#ifndef Test_hpp
#define Test_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class ClassA {
public:
    void foo(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& ov);
};

#endif /* Test_hpp */
```

and `Test.cpp`

```
#include "Test.hpp"

using namespace std;

void ClassA::foo(vector<vector<int> >& ov) {
    return;
}
```

I still got the mangled name `_ZN6ClassA3fooERi`.
But I noticed that there was an error from clang:

```
Test.hpp:11:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

However, I can build it successfully by either Xcode or xcodebuild command.

Comment: These are simply two distinct overloads of `ClassA::getElements`. Do you have any reason to believe that these are supposed to be the same overload? Please show a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
The root cause is when parsing my source file, there is a fatal error 'xxx.h' file not found. Once I fixed this error manually, Clang could output the correct results.